# Mule global catch exception not being called

Tags: mule

I'm using the global exception strategy at this link

[Global Catch Exception Strategy is not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674605/global-catch-exception-strategy-is-not-used)

I use a ref to this in each of my flow footers and have also used defaultExceptionStrategy-ref="catchExceptionStrategy" as shown in the link. But this exception

```
 org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: null
 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 ...
```

is not being caught by my global exception. My assumption was that this is a message exception and the flow refs would therefore direct it to the global catch. Also that the defaultExceptionStrategy-ref configuration would direct any other exceptions to the global catch.

Answer (score 1):

The log you are showing proves that the exception strategy is actually called but there has been a concurrent modification exception on it. In order to help you further we would need to understand better what is in you message when the exception happens and the actual xml of your exception strategy.